# How to pass arguments to function as then()'s argument in Promise chain with previous resolved value being kept?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am running JavaScript in node v5.7.1. I am trying to find a smart way to pass arguments to the function as then()'s argument while the previous resolved value still being kept without interfering each other.

```
var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    resolve('world!');
});

function logger (prefix) {
    return function (resolvedValue) {
        console.log(prefix + resolvedValue);
    }
}

p.then(logger('Hello '));
```

This is what I can figure out so far. My aim is to let promise p to do something which will take some time, such as a database operation. After that, p returns the resolved value and I want to pass it as well as other arguments to the callback as `then()`'s argument.

But I need to write a function which return another function again and again to reach my goal. Is there any other smart ways to do this? Does spread/rest operator `...` help in this case?

Comment: Closures *are* a smart way to do this already. No, rest parameters don't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures are totally fine to do this. You could also use a function expression:

```
function logger (prefix, resolvedValue) {
    console.log(prefix + resolvedValue);
}

p.then(x => logger('Hello ', x));
```

or even an array and destructuring:

```
function logger ([prefix, resolvedValue]) {
    console.log(prefix + resolvedValue);
}

Promise.all(['Hello', p]).then(logger);
```

Comment: These two are very interesting and constructive. Thank you for your proposal. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var p = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    resolve('world!');
});

function logger (prefix,resolvedValue) {
        console.log(prefix + resolvedValue);
}

p.then(function (resolvedValue){
logger('Hello ',resolvedValue)
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that could work. But I lean to make the promise chain more compact because that would improve the readability of the code.